# How to align a label to the top middle of the div control and draw a rectangle around it?

Tags: javascript, css, html, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a label inside a div control.I want to align it to the top middle of the div control and draw a rectangle around that text.And also i want to display the characters of that label's text one by one from left to right .

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: I added a css style of vertical-align: top to label, It has taken the lable to the top of the division vertically, but not horizontally.

Comment: HTML:
 
        <div id="imagecontainer">
          <image id="imagehome"/>
        </div>
 
in css:
   
      #imagehome{
  
         vertical-align: top;
 
              }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to center the text to the middle of the div horizontal, you simply need to style it with

```
div#ctrl {
     text-align: center
}
```

To have a rectangle around the text, you need to define a border, probably with padding and margin:

```
div#ctrl span {
    border: 1px #333 solid;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

You need to use javascript to animate the text, made easier with jQuery. Here a link to working example I whipped of what you were looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/5QdPh/

In the future try to do a little more research and ask questions about specific problems that have not been answered before. All of this is basic, well documented stuff.

Comment: The js fiddle stopped working, so here is another one: http://jsfiddle.net/thundercracker/stDPd/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for the first part:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/VdmFV/

Fot the second part you'd need some fancy javascript / jQuery which you should attempt yourself first then come back here for pointers.

Comment: Thanks all for your replies.It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>

#control {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#ddd;
    text-align: center
}
#label {
    border:1px solid red;
}
</style>

<div id='control'>
    <span id='label'></span>
</div>

<script>
var label = document.getElementById("label");
var msg = "Message";
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval( function() {
    label.innerHTML = msg.substr(0,i);
    i++;
    if ( i == msg.length ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000)
</script>
```